# Do I need the .NET 4.0 Client Framework if I install .NET 4.0 Full on Windows 7?

Tags: .net, windows-7, .net-framework-version

I want to completely prepare an x86 Windows 7 PC for any existing or new .NET apps that might exist. Which versions of .NET Framework should I install? Windows 7 appears to ship with .NET 3.0 or [.NET 3.5.1 inbuilt](http://www.msigeek.com/2390/what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-which-version-of-the-os). Which means I need to install:

- .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 - [Full, 230 MB](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=22) - Do I need this since Windows 7 includes it by default?
- .NET Framework 4.0 - [Full, 35 MB](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/4/5641DA81-E6FA-4550-9F80-A1D862D9CFAA/dotNetFx40_Full_x86.exe)
- .NET Framework 4.0 - [Client, 28 MB](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/1/8/318161B8-9874-48E4-BB38-9EB82C5D6358/dotNetFx40_Client_x86.exe) - Do I need this if I install 4.0 Full?

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, .NET Framerwork 3.5 ships with Windows 7, so you must install .NET Framework 4.0 Full. Client libraries allows you only to execute .NET programs.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you do .NET development which would require the full framework, you should install .NET Framework 4.0 Client.